# Why is IDialog of the bot framework generic?

Tags: c#, botframework

All examples based on the Microsoft bot framework use the generic `IDialog` interface as `IDialog<object>`.

What is the purpose of this interface being generic? The generic is used as an `out` type and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.idialog-1?view=botbuilder-3.8)) says:

> [...] suspendable conversational process that produces a result of
>   type TResult

But I don't find any place where this result would actually be used/demonstrated. The only demos about returning values use the context's `Done<T>()` which is independent of the dialog's type parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it's related to the `context.Done<T>` but it becomes much more clear when you think this in the context of multiple dialogs.

When you call (or forward an incoming message) to a new dialog, you need to specify a `ResumeAfter<T>` method, which is basically the one that will be called when you call to `context.Done` (or `context.Fail`) in the new dialog.

```
context.Call(new NameDialog(), this.NameDialogResumeAfter);
```

where `NameDialog` definition is:

```
[Serializable]
public class NameDialog : IDialog<string>
```

As you can now guess, the `<T>` on the `ResumeAfter` method correlates with the `<T>` specified in the dialog. So, if your dialog is `IDialog<string>` your `ResumeAfter<T>` method will look like:

```
private async Task NameDialogResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
```

If in the `context.Done` you send another type, it will likely fail at the moment you perform an `await` of the `result`.

You can review the following samples:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-BasicMultiDialog
- https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs